# Show Bootstrap's Alert on successful Submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to work on bootstrap's alert. Particulary this:

`<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div>`

I wanted it to pop-up on the modal after I successfully hit the submit button. How do I do that?

Here are my codes:

```
<!--____________________________ADD AGENT________________________--> 
<div class="modal fade" id="addAgent" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
             <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <form role="form" action="php/addAgent.php" method="POST">           
             <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Agent</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name"    name="fname">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">                                  
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Middle Name"   name="mname">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"     name="lname">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div><!--___________FORM GROUP_____________-->

                                <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <label for="sel1">Type:</label>                                     
                                        <select class="form-control" name="agentType" id="sel1">
                                            <option value="1">Broker</option>
                                            <option value="2">Agent</option>
                                            <option value="3">Sub-Agent</option>
                                        </select> 
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <label for="sel1">Project:</label>                                      
                                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                                            <option>Mezza</option>
                                                <option>Tivoli Gardens</option>
                                            <option>Verawoods Residences</option>
                                        </select> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"   id="email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="contact">Contact Number</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact" id="contact">
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <label for="homeAdd">Home Address</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="homeAdd" id="homeAdd">
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                        </form>         
                </div>
             </div>          </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                <input  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit"/>  
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Close</button>                                   
             </div>
             </div>
</div>
</div><!--______________________ADD AGENTS MODAL_______________________-->

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
```

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php

$user="root"; $pass=""; $db="realesate";

$db = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db);

//check connection
if ( $db->connect_error) {
die('Connect Error: ' . $db->connect_errno . ': ' .  $db->connect_error );
}

//insert data
$sql = "insert into agent (AgentFName , AgentMName , AgentLName , AgentContact , AgentEmail, AgentAddress , agentType) 
    values ( 
    '{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['fname'])}'    ,
    '{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['mname'])}'    ,
    '{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['lname'])}'    ,
    '{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['contact'])}'  ,   
    '{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])}'    ,
    '{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['homeAdd'])}'  ,
    '{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['agentType'])}')";
$insert = $db->query($sql); 
    if ($insert) {
        echo"";


    }

//close connection
$db->close();
?>
```

How do I do that after I successfully added the values on my database?

Comment: You are going to need to use ajax (e.g. Submit using jQuery) , else submitting will refresh your browser.

Comment: @RobertoNovelo How do I use ajax? Any good reference?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using AJAX to call `addAgent.php` and your PHP and HTML are in one file, then one way would be to set a variable in your PHP like so:

```
if ($insert) {
    $alert_success = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div>';
}
```

Then anywhere in your HTML you can add a line that echos that variable.

```
<?php
    echo $alert_success;
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't recognize the variable $alert_success when echoed in HTML

Comment: It should be if your INSERT worked correctly. Your code is all in one page? What's the exact error?

Comment: It inserted succesfully. My HTML and PHP code is separated. I tried to put my php on the same page but it says that the indexes in $_POST are undefined.

Comment: When you put them in one page, did you remove `action='addAgent.php'` from the `<form>` tag? If not, try setting action to simply `action=""`

Comment: Did you see indexes error as soon as the page loaded, or after you clicked the submit button?

Comment: Ok, with PHP and HTML all in one page. Add `name='btn_submit'` to the submit button. Then, in your PHP surround all of it with `if (isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) { `   then end it with `}`.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: alert_success in C:\xampp\htdocs\RealEstateMaintenance\index.php on line 29

Comment: ok, just add $alert_success = ""; to the top of the PHP and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a submit handler for your form:

```
// Add an ID to your form
$( "#formID" ).submit(function( event ) {

  // Stop form from submitting normally
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get some values from elements on the page:
  var $form = $( this ),
    term = $form.find( "input[name='s']" ).val(),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );

  // Send the data using post
  var posting = $.post( url, { s: term } );

  // Put the results in a div
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    $(".modal-body, #orModalBodyID"). append('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Post Success</div>')
  });
});
```

You can find more information on jQuery's post() method @ their [API documentation website](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)